# elementwise function of low rank approximation

Tags: approximation

I recently ran into an interesting result.

I have a matrix $D$ containing pairwise distances between all points in a dataset. This matrix is converted to a similarity matrix $S$ via an RBF kernel.

Because calculating the full distance matrix is expensive, I use randomized linear algebra techniques to approximate $S$. As $S$ is positive definite, there are some specialised techniques to find good approximations cheaply. For my application, the approximation performs very well.

In my research, I also tried approximating $D$ and converting the approximation to an approximate $S$ afterwards. I expected that this wouldn't perform well, because I thought a low rank approximation of $D$ would not approximate small elements well and these small elements become large elements in $S$. However, the experiments indicate that it performs very well.

Can anyone help me explain these results? Am I wrong in thinking that the low rank approximation will not approximate small elements well?

Comment: low rank matrices are not typically sparse, so there's no reason that a low rank approximation can't handle a matrix that is dense with lots of small elements.

Comment: i was thinking about it like this: let's say each element is off by 0.001 times the norm of the matrix. Then the large elements would be approximated accurately in a relative sense, but the small ones could be off by a lot. And the kernel then turns these errors that are large in a relative sense into errors that are large in an absolute sense and ruins the approximation.

Comment: a low-rank approximation will have a good approximation of a few (usually the largest) eigenvalues of a matrix. And so it will typically be bad for the small eigenvalues. But there is not really a straight-forward relation between a small eigenvalue (or its eigenvector or invariabnt subsapce) and small entries of the matrix.